# if "14" LEQ "7" () failure

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, compare

I'm making a program that changes coordinate values in a .gcd file, i got the single coordinate lines working but the lines with double coordinates aren't. The program is supposed to split the double coordinates up and run them separately as single coordinates. To accomplish this, I sort the form the coordinates could be in to different sections of code to give the right output. Using the length of the string I can sort them easily. While programming this I ran into a simple problem of a

```
IF " " LEQ " " ()
```

command. Given values it gets the wrong outcome. A good example is:

```
@echo off

:start
if "14" LEQ "7" goto next
echo this should be printed
pause
exit /b

:next
echo this shouldn't be printed
pause
exit /b
```

Removing the " " seems to fix the issue, but I need to compare variables, which can have spaces, justifying the parenthesis. So the question is:

Why does the interpreter get to the wrong outcome, and how can I easily fix this?

Thanks, -Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if "14" LEQ "7" goto next
```

This does a lexicographic string comparison, where "14" < "7" because the first non-equal character 1 < 7.

As you noted, if you drop the quotes the following will do a numerical comparison.

```
if 14 LEQ 7 goto next
```

This is consistent with the `if /?` help:

> These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.

The quote (which is part of the strings being compared in the first case) is not a numeric digit, so no conversion to numbers is performed, and the comparison is done on the strings by lexical rules.

You also say that `but I need to compare variables, which can have spaces`. However a numeric value does/can not contain spaces and does not require quotes. On the contrary, once enclosed in quotes it's no longer a numeric value, but a string. So you'll have to decide/distinguish in advance whether you want to compare numerical vs. string values.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question perfectly.